# SSIS Import Multiple Files Ignore blank lines

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have the below Script Task in SSIS to import multiple text files into multiple tables.  It creates the tables on the fly based on the text file names.

However, some of the text files have 1 or more blank lines at the end - how do I exclude these?  The text files are coming from a 3rd party so I cannot resolve at source.

This is my code:

```
{
            SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["xxxxxxxxx"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
         //   MessageBox.Show(myADONETConnection.ConnectionString, "xxxxxxxxxx");

            string line1 = "";
            //Reading file names one by one
            string SourceDirectory = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            // TODO: Add your code here
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDirectory);
            foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            {
                // do something with fileName
             //   MessageBox.Show(fileName);
                string columname = "";


                //Reading first line of each file and assign to variable
                System.IO.StreamReader file2 =
                new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);


                string filenameonly = ((((fileName.Replace(SourceDirectory, "")).Replace(".txt", "")).Replace("\\", "")).Replace("-", "_"));
                line1 = (" IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo]." + filenameonly + "') AND type in (N'U'))DROP TABLE [dbo]." + filenameonly + " Create Table dbo." + filenameonly + "([" + file2.ReadLine().Replace("|", "] NVARCHAR(500),[") + "] NVARCHAR(500))").Replace(".txt", "");


                file2.Close();

             //   MessageBox.Show(line1.ToString());

                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(line1, myADONETConnection);
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();          

             //   MessageBox.Show("TABLE IS CREATED");

                //Writing Data of File Into Table
                int counter = 0;
                string line;

                System.IO.StreamReader SourceFile =
                new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
                while ((line = SourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    if (counter == 0)
                    {
                        columname = line.ToString();
                        columname = "[" + columname.Replace("|", "],[") + "]";
                      //  MessageBox.Show(columname);
                      //  MessageBox.Show("INside IF");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        //  MessageBox.Show("Inside ELSE");


                    while ((line = SourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        line = line.Trim();
                        if (line.Length > 0)
                        {
                            string query = "Insert into dbo." + filenameonly + "(" + columname + ") VALUES('" + line.Replace("|", "','") + "')";

                            SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
                            myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }


                    }

                    counter++;

                }

                SourceFile.Close();
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe by checking the line's lenght, `line.Replace("|","").Length` before insert command

Answer (score 1):

I usually check if length of line > 0

```
            while ((line = SourceFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    //put your code here
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks - I did this and it ignores the blank lines - however, it is now also ignoring the 1st row of data after the column headings in each import.

Comment: How can this change affect a row that has data?  You must have counter++; in the wrong place.

Comment: I have tried it elsewhere and then it doesn't import anything?  Its currently after the else as per last edit

Comment: Why do you have two WHILE loops?  You should only have one.

Comment: because I am creating the first line of the SQL table based on the first line of the text file.  The first is for the column headings, the 2nd for the actual detail

Comment: You can't do that.  Have one while loop.  Then have IF statement for count == 0 and when zero handle the first line.  Then the ELSE for after the header.  You can't have two while loop both reading SourceFile.

Comment: the original code was working though - just stumbling with the blank lines - I'm lost?

Comment: The original code I do not think was completing.  It was only processing the first file and would of gotten an exception when processing the the first file and terminated.  The update is now processing more than one file so you are seeing new errors that you didn't see before.

Comment: It was processing the text files and creating the multiple tables in SQL - I could see them in SSMS

Comment: I can't explain the differences you are seeing between the old code and new code.  The changes you made should not affect the first row unless there are blank lines at the beginning of the files.